# Cannot create a script project in DaVinci Configurator

Tags: java, groovy, gradlew, autosar

I'm trying to learn how to write scripts for Davinci Configurator(DvCfg) and from the beginning I encountered an issue in creating new script projects.

I created the project from the DvCfg, choosing `"Default Automation Script"`, given a name and a path to the location.

For `"Gradle Distribution URL"` I tried the default option and custom, but none of them worked.

When I press `Finish`, I get the error from below:

> *java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create the new script Project. Execution of gradlew failed with return code: 1. Project created in
>   folder D:\Users\romandi\Desktop\Script\hghg Starting gradlew build ...
>   :compileJava NO-SOURCE :compileGroovy FAILED FAILURE: Build failed
>   with an exception.
>   * What went wrong: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':detachedConfiguration1'.
>
> Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-ant:2.5.0.   Searched in the
>   following locations:
>         file:/S:/70_Tools/10_AR_ToolChain/DaVinciConfigurator/Core/AutomationInterface/libs/ivy-2.5.0.xml
>         file:/S:/70_Tools/10_AR_ToolChain/DaVinciConfigurator/Core/AutomationInterface/libs/groovy-ant-2.5.0-indy.jar
>         file:/S:/70_Tools/10_AR_ToolChain/DaVinciConfigurator/BswmdModel/ivy-2.5.0.xml
>         file:/S:/70_Tools/10_AR_ToolChain/DaVinciConfigurator/BswmdModel/groovy-ant-2.5.0-indy.jar   Required by:
>         project :
>   * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. BUILD FAILED in 3s 1 actionable task: 1 executed    at
>   com.vector.cfg.gui.scripting.assistant.CreateScriptOperation.execute(SourceFile:123)
>     at
>   com.vector.cfg.gui.scripting.assistant.ExecutionPage$FinalExecutionStep.performFinish(SourceFile:73)
>     at
>   com.vector.cfg.core.operation.assistant.Step.finish(SourceFile:112)
>     at
>   com.vector.cfg.gui.core.ctrl.assistant.GenericAssistant.performFinish(SourceFile:261)
>     at
>   com.vector.cfg.gui.core.assistant.AssistantPartContainer2$1.run(SourceFile:284)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Execution of gradlew failed
>   with return code: 1.  at
>   com.vector.cfg.gui.scripting.assistant.CreateScriptOperation.dC(SourceFile:190)
>     at
>   com.vector.cfg.gui.scripting.assistant.CreateScriptOperation.execute(SourceFile:106)
>     ... 5 more*

Please help
Thak you

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8avKt.png)

Comment: This is very specific. I guess this would be a perfect question for the vendor‘s support hotline.

Answer (score 0):

The SIP update to version 5.18.60_SP4 solved the issue.